# PWA not working on live website but is working on localhost with npx serve -s build

Tags: reactjs, typescript, frontend, progressive-web-apps

This is my first time trying to make an PWA App and it is working on localhost if i run npx serve -s build but when I'm diploying it in production i get next error:
**Error during service worker registration: TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://....netlify.app/') with script ('https://....netlify.app/service-worker.js'): A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.**

I'm using basic template generated using command `npx create-react-app my-app --template cra-template-pwa-typescript`

service-worker.ts is located in public folder and serviceWorkerRegistration.ts in src folder.

service-worker.ts code

```
/// <reference lib="webworker" />
import { clientsClaim } from 'workbox-core';
import { ExpirationPlugin } from 'workbox-expiration';
import { precacheAndRoute, createHandlerBoundToURL } from 'workbox-precaching';
import { registerRoute } from 'workbox-routing';
import { StaleWhileRevalidate } from 'workbox-strategies';

declare const self: ServiceWorkerGlobalScope;

clientsClaim();
precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST);
const fileExtensionRegexp = new RegExp('/[^/?]+\\.[^/]+$');
registerRoute(
  ({ request, url }: { request: Request; url: URL }) => {
    if (request.mode !== 'navigate') {
      return false;
    }

    if (url.pathname.startsWith('/_')) {
      return false;
    }
    if (url.pathname.match(fileExtensionRegexp)) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  },
  createHandlerBoundToURL(process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/index.html')
);

registerRoute(
  ({ url }) => url.origin === self.location.origin && url.pathname.endsWith('.png'),
  new StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: 'images',
    plugins: [
      new ExpirationPlugin({ maxEntries: 50 }),
    ],
  })
);

self.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  if (event.data && event.data.type === 'SKIP_WAITING') {
    self.skipWaiting();
  }
});
```

serviceWorkerRegistration.ts code:

```
  const isLocalhost = Boolean(
  window.location.hostname === 'localhost' ||
  window.location.hostname === '[::1]' ||
  window.location.hostname.match(/^127(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}$/)
);

type Config = {
  onSuccess?: (registration: ServiceWorkerRegistration) => void;
  onUpdate?: (registration: ServiceWorkerRegistration) => void;
};

export function register(config?: Config) {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && 'serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    const publicUrl = new URL(process.env.PUBLIC_URL, window.location.href);
    if (publicUrl.origin !== window.location.origin) {
      return;
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
      const swUrl = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/service-worker.js`;

      if (isLocalhost) {
        checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl, config);
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(() => {
          console.log(
            'This web app is being served cache-first by a service ' +
            'worker. To learn more, visit https://cra.link/PWA'
          );
        });
      } else {
        registerValidSW(swUrl, config);
      }
    });
  }
}

function registerValidSW(swUrl: string, config?: Config) {
  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register(swUrl)
    .then((registration) => {
      registration.onupdatefound = () => {
        const installingWorker = registration.installing;
        if (installingWorker == null) {
          return;
        }
        installingWorker.onstatechange = () => {
          if (installingWorker.state === 'installed') {
            if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
              console.log(
                'New content is available and will be used when all ' +
                'tabs for this page are closed. See https://cra.link/PWA.'
              );

              if (config && config.onUpdate) {
                config.onUpdate(registration);
              }
            } else {
              console.log('Content is cached for offline use.');
              if (config && config.onSuccess) {
                config.onSuccess(registration);
              }
            }
          }
        };
      };
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error);
    });
}


function checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl: string, config?: Config) {
  fetch(swUrl, {
    headers: { 'Service-Worker': 'script' },
  })
    .then((response) => {
      const contentType = response.headers.get('content-type');
      if (
        response.status === 404 ||
        (contentType != null && contentType.indexOf('javascript') === -1)
      ) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then((registration) => {
          registration.unregister().then(() => {
            window.location.reload();
          });
        });
      } else {
        registerValidSW(swUrl, config);
      }
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log('No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.');
    });
}

export function unregister() {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready
      .then((registration) => {
        registration.unregister();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error.message);
      });
  }
}
```

In index calling as `serviceWorker.register();`

In manifest.json :  `"start_url": "/",`

Can anybody help me to figure out how to fix this error?
Thanks

Comment: "A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script." The `service-worker.js` file is not getting deployed.